# Prove, that for any $0<a<1$, $-\frac{a}{1+a}<\ln(1-a)<-a.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

1. Prove, that for any $a>0$, $$a>\ln(1-a)>\frac{a}{1+a}.$$
2. Prove, that for any $0<a<1$, $$-\frac{a}{1+a}<\ln(1-a)<-a.$$

Proof of 1: We will prove (1) by doing a proof by converse. Assume that $$a>\ln(1-a)>\frac{a}{1+a}.$$ We need to show that this is true for $a>0$. Well, when $a\neq 0$ 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
a>\ln(1-a)>\frac{a}{1+a} & \iff \frac{a}{a}>\frac{\ln(1-a)}{a}>\frac{a}{1+a}\cdot \frac{1}{a} \\
& \iff 1>\frac{\ln(1-a)}{a}>\frac{1}{1+a} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
This implies that $$1>\frac{1}{a+1} \iff a+1>1 \iff a>0.$$ Hence we have shown that for any $a>0$, $$a>\ln(1-a)>\frac{a}{1+a}.$$

Now for 2, I feel that $a>0$ comes directly from part a. How do I show that $1>a$?

Comment: You have not shown that the implication $1 > \frac{\ln(1-a)}{a} > \frac{1}{1+a} \implies 1 > \frac{1}{a+1}$ goes the other way.

Comment: I think the problem is with your logic.  First off you can't prove something by proving the "converse".  Do you perhaps mean the "contra-positive"?  Secondly, what you have assumed: $a>\ln(1-a)>\frac 1{1+a}$ is neither the converse nor the contra-positive.  Is there a typo?

Comment: I think OP meant that he would do a "proof in reverse" with the implication in each step going both ways

Comment: Why is the condition in 1. that $a>0$ when $\ln(1-a)$ is undefined when $a\geq 1$? There seems something confused between 1. and 2. The conditions of 1. and 2. are essentially the same, but they give different bounds for the same function. Is 1. supposed to be about $\ln(1+a)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

To prove $a>\ln(1-a)$ we define $f(x)=x-\ln (1-x).$ We have that $f(0)=0.$ Now, $f'(x)=1+\frac{1}{1-x}>0$ on $(0,1).$ Thus, $f$ is strictly increasing. That is, for any $x\in (0,1)$ one has

$$0=f(0)<f(x)\implies x> \ln (1-x).$$ Note that $x<1$ because in other case $\ln (1-x)$ doesn't exist.

**Note** With respect to the inequality $\ln(1-a)>\frac{a}{1+a}$ note that when $0<a<1$ the LHS is negative and the RHS is positive. So, this inequality can't be satisfied.

To show $\ln(1-a)<-a$ consider $f(x)=-x-\ln(1-x).$ One has $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)>0$ on $(0,1).$ Thus, proceeding as before you get the inequality.

Finally, to show $-\frac{a}{1+a}<\ln(1-a)$ consider $f(x)=\ln(1-x)+\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{1}{2}.$ One has $f'(x)<0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=0.$ Conclude from here the inequality.

Comment: By other cases, do you mean $ln(1-a)>\frac{a}{1+a}$?

Comment: Please check the inequality  $ln(1-a)>\frac{a}{1+a}.$ This doesn't hold for $0<a<1.$

Comment: Okie dokie. However, (2) does hold for $0<a<1$

Comment: I have edited the answer in the way I think it can be helpful to deal with all cases. Please, comment if some point is not clear enough.